# Meteor - how to deal with npm peer requirements not installed?

Tags: meteor, npm

I have a Meteor application (1.3.2.4) and when I run it I get:

```
WARNING: npm peer requirements not installed:
react@15.3.1 installed, react@0.14.x needed
react-addons-update@15.3.1 installed, react-addons-update@0.14.x needed
react-addons-pure-render-mixin@15.3.1 installed, react-addons-pure-render-mixin@0.14.x needed

Read more about installing npm peer dependencies:
http://guide.meteor.com/using-packages.html#peer-npm-dependencies

/home/tidee/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.17uhn8z++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267
throw(ex);
^
Error: Cannot find module 'react/lib/ReactDefaultPerf'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/tidee/app/tidee-meteor/node_modules/react-addons-perf/index.js:1:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

In my package.json file in the root of the application I have the following dependency:

```
"react": "^15.0.1"
```

So, where is 15.3.1 coming from - is Meteor installing it?

Secondly, it's not telling me which other npm packages require a lower version of React to be installed - how do I find this out?

Comment: The issue is not `v15.0.1` vs `v15.3.1`, but `v14.x` vs `v15.x`.